# Rails: devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am new with rails, I wanted to do something that in my mind shoud be easy but I am not sure how it's done.

**presenting the Situation**

I have an App using rails in API mode for my backend server, and Angular2 as my front end server. To authentify the users, I use the gem : devise_token_auth.

**Problem**

In my App, I have many types of users with different permissions. For example, Directors, assistant-Directors ... my question is how can I implement that? I added a field user_type to the table but is that all ?

Comment: Normally this is done by adding a `role` field and possibly using [an authorization gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to do permission checks.

Comment: I am already using an Authentification gem :[link](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth). and I added the field role with a migration

Comment: Authentication is one step, authorization is how you set up rules for what those roles can and cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can implement this functionality.

1. You can check 
   https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan
   for role based authorization and access management.
2. Add a column `role` to `User` model to keep track of user permissions.

And you can always associate different permissions to different roles you define.